# Can an algorithm for this be done in one line?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 3 variables: `total`, `paid`, and `payment`

Lets give an example to simplify the problem:

> ```
> total = 100
> paid = 10
> ```
>
> If a new `payment` comes in which value is `200`, `paid` should now
>   become `100` 
>  If a new `payment` comes in which value is `50`,
>   `paid` should now become `60` 
>  If a new `payment` comes in which
>   value is `90`, `paid` should now become `100`

I think you get what im going for.

Can `paid` be calculated in one line, without using `if` or the `?` operator?

Comment: Probably. Have you tried anything? This is not a free coding/homework service.

Comment: First: Why? Second: Have you tried yet?

Comment: Are you trying to add payment to paid? Is that it?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it can be done, jeez, i'll delete the question then if it bothers you all so hard

Comment: @m_bale Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You just show no research/coding effort.

Comment: @tnw How do I show research/coding on an algorithm this simple? What's even the point of showing the things I tried if they are all simple math that obviously didn't work? I just didn't think of the Math.Min() function that's a pretty neat, short and simple solution, just what I wanted.

Comment: @m_bale Did you even read the link in my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

`paid = Math.Min(total, payment+paid)`

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I don't think this was such a stupid question was it?

Comment: It's the percentage paid. Is that right? You should add that to your question @m_bale.

Comment: @james no, it's not